# If two continuous random variables (events) are independent, does it mean they have different probability distributions?

Tags: probability

Intuitively I know the answer is no, because we can, for example, have two random real number generators with the same probability distribution, and yet they are independent.

But I don't know how to put it formally with mathematical language.

Comment: Your argument in the first paragraph of the question looks completely fine. It is not clear what more than that you want.

Comment: As you pointed out, simply consider two independent random variable, each having the same distribution. (Or, is your question about whether such thing can actually be realized?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $\Omega := [0,1]\times [0,1]$, $\mathcal{F} := \mathcal{B}(\Omega)$ Borel-field and define $X:\Omega \to \mathbb R , X(x,y) := x$ and $Y:\Omega \to \mathbb R , Y(x,y) := y$.

Define $\mathbb P (A) := \int_A dt ds $ for $A\in \mathcal F $. Then $X$ and $Y$ are independent and identically distributed with $X\sim$ Uniform$[0,1]$ (continuous distribution).